# Is $\aleph_0 = \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Some very wise people here have just told me that  $\aleph_0 = \mathbb{N}$, i.e. that the cardinality of the set of natural numbers is just the set of natural numbers itself. Is this now the general consensus in mathematics, real analysis in particular? Or have I got completely the wrong end of the stick as usual?

Comment: First of all $\mathbb{N} \neq\aleph_0$ the cardinality of the natural numbers is $\aleph_0$.

Comment: @Aleksandar Thanks. That's what I thought.

Comment: I would write $\aleph_0= | \mathbb N |$.

Comment: Just an example: the cardinality of the set {a;a;c;d} is 4, is 4={a;a;c;d} ?

Comment: @Renato, It may be if $a, b, c, d$ happen to equal $0$, $1$, $2$ and $3$.

Comment: Why would you care what people in real analysis have to say about $\aleph_0$? It would be as relevant as asking a set theorist what is $\pi$.

Comment: Ok now this can't happen @HenningMakholm

Comment: @AsafKaragila, haha. That's an odd tag...

Comment: @Aleksandar Incorrect.

Comment: @GitGud, I wouldn't say its a matter of correct/incorrect. This is a matter of conventions and/or how you interpret that notation.

Comment: @gob: Not just the tag. Read the body of the question too. He's asking people in real analysis whether or not a set theoretic convention holds in analysis about $\aleph_0$. As well f they care, and as if I care as a set theorist what they will say.

Comment: @goblin Do you know more than one definition of cardinality? I only know one and it leaves no room for interpretation, $\mathbb N=\aleph_0$.

Comment: @GitGud: There's [Scott's Trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott%27s_trick), which is useful when working in ZF without choice but with foundation. In this representation $\aleph_0$ is the set of all countably infinite sets of rank $\omega$, so instead we have $\omega\in\aleph_0$.

Comment: @GitGud, well sure. Without the axiom of choice, the Von Neumann cardinal assignment doesn't work correctly, and you have to revert to thinking of cardinal numbers as being "sets up to isomorphism" or "equivalence classes of sets up to isomorphism" or whatever. This can be internalized to the universe of sets using [Scott's trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott's_trick).

Comment: @GitGud: There may be only one decent version of cardinality in ZFC, but there is at least one other implementation of $\mathbb{N}$ that's not totally awful.

Comment: I think it is probably true that if you asked a bunch of real analysis "Is it true that $\{0,1\}=2$?" they would probably look at you like you are crazy, but a set theorist would say "Of course."  If you take numbers as primitive elements in a theory, there is no need to worry about how they are defined and what they 'really' are.  And if you are comfortable doing that with numbers, why not with infinite cardinals?

Comment: In ZFC set theory, we have:$$3=\{0,1,2\}\\ =\{\{\},\{0\},\{0,1\}\}\\ =\{\{\},\{\{\}\},\{\{\},\{0\}\}\}\\ =\{\{\},\{\{\}\},\{\{\},\{\{\}\}\}\}$$ _Everything_ is a set.

Comment: If you assume everything is a set, then you are forced to conclude that given two distinct natural numbers, then at least one must be a non-empty set -- another bizarre notion in real analysis .

Comment: Is it really that bizarre? Does it ever even come up? Is it any weirder than reals as Dedekind cuts?

Comment: Dan, the purpose of a foundation theory is to be able and interpret mathematical construction as objects of the theory. The objects of set theory are *sets*. The ***entire*** point in showing that you can define $2=\{0,1\}=\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}$ is to show that you *can* in fact interpret the natural numbers, and by extension through all the axioms, the real numbers and so on, as sets. Which sets? It doesn't ***really*** matter. But then $\aleph_0$ is a purely set theoretical concept, and it's kinda weird that you compare it to the natural numbers.

Comment: And if it bothers you that much that natural numbers are distinct sets and at most one of them is non-empty, then by all means, develop a new theory. Or work with $\sf ZFCU$ which allows urelements. But as far as *foundational* theories go, the urelements are unnecessary and bothersome when it comes to $\sf ZF$-like theories. Which is why we don't use them in general. But again, this is just a proof of concept, that we *can* do that. Nobody *really* cares about how you do that. And since set theory is *not* about the interpretation of these objects, we just pick one way to do it and we move on

Comment: Or work in $\mathsf{NFU}$ where urelements have a mathematical purpose and you can use the intuitively appealing Frege natural numbers. With some other trade-offs along the way... :P

Comment: @AsafKaragila No need to develop a new system. In number theory, they start with Peano's axioms. No number theorist  ever considers that a natural number might be a set with elements in it. There is no need to.

Comment: Dan, *so what*? You're *completely* ignoring everything I said. Set theory, as a foundational theory is *supposed* to take everything in mathematics and turn it into sets to its best ability. Sure, you can work in set theories with urelements like $\sf NFU$ or $\sf ZFCU$. But those *can* end up either too weak for some things, or unnecessarily complicated with the urelements for other things. I don't know how to make it any clearer, so I'm going to stop trying to repeat myself again and again and again. If you have a beef against set theoretic foundations, find a better one. Good luck.

Comment: In Peano arithmetic, they aren't sets. However, Peano arithmetic can't prove everything; there are statements that PA can neither prove true nor false. An example is Goodstein's theorem, a true theorem about natural numbers and exponentiation, which can't be proven in PA, but _can_ be proven in ZFC. (ZFC _also_ can't prove everything, but it's still much stronger than PA.)

Comment: Besides, you can't do analysis in PA anyway, since it can't quantify over arbitrary functions.

Comment: @columbus8myhw It's funny how the first-order crowd appropriated the term "Peano arithmetic" for themselves. It seems most authors who care about such things start with Peano's five axioms *and* some kind set theory, so induction becomes $\forall P\subset \mathbb{N}:[0 \in P$, etc.

Comment: If it's not first order then it's not generally called "Peano arithmetic", it's just "arithmetic".

Answer (score 13):

There's nothing deep going on here. Its just that:

- Its often convenient to identify $\mathbb{N}$ with the least infinite ordinal $\omega$.
- Its often convenient to identify each well-orderable cardinal number $\kappa$ with the least ordinal $\alpha$ such that $|\alpha| = \kappa$. This is called the [von Neumann cardinal assigment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_cardinal_assignment).

Under these identifications, we find that $\mathbb{N} = \omega = \aleph_0 = |\mathbb{N}|.$ I wouldn't read too much into it though.

Comment: Interesting. Another instance were it seems the conventions of ZFC theory are not widely adopted outside the narrow specialty of set theory itself.

Comment: @DanChristensen The issue is much more serious than field-dependent conventions, for in asserting that $\mathbb N\neq \aleph_0$, one must be able to tell what $\aleph_0$ is and, of course, when one defines it, the equality is trivial.

Comment: @GitGud Are you saying it is impossible to formally construct $\aleph_0$ as the cardinality of  $\mathbb{N}$  and as something distinct from  $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @DanChristensen I don't know enough to answer your question. See goblin's and Maurice's comments on the question. But, *as things are usually done*, the answer is trivial if one defines cardinal of a set. If one doesn't define cardinality and maneuver around using bijections, then the question doesn't make sense due the choice of not defining the concept of "cardinal of a set".

Comment: Let $\mathbb{N}'$ be $\bigcap\{x:\emptyset\in x\wedge\{\{z\}:z\in x\}\subseteq x\}$. One can recursively define all the usual arithmetic, and its not identical with $\aleph_0$. But that's not the set that's conventionally used for the naturals.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine I think I would prefer to simply start with some form of Peano's axioms and  to get on with doing mathematics. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Peano's axioms by themselves? That wouldn't be very helpful if analysis is your concern.

Comment: Not to mention I think you missed the point. Curiosity was expressed about implementations of $\aleph_0$ that differ from one for $\mathbb{N}$; I was offering an example of the converse, which is easier to find, not recommending the Zermelo naturals.

Answer (score 10):

The objects in set theory are sets. Only sets in $\sf ZFC$ and its related theories. This means that if you want to interpret a mathematical object in set theory you need to assign it a set.

Of course you are free to assign to it any set that you wish, as long as you have the axiom of replacement set theory is more or less interpretation agnostic (in the sense that it proves that two interpretations are generally exchangeable). But still you need to pick some interpretation, to at least show one way of doing this is possible.

So just like the standard method for interpreting ordered pairs is via the definition by Kuratowski, the standard way of assigning cardinals to well-orderable sets is by picking the least ordinal of that cardinality as a representative. So we define the cardinals for infinite [well-orderable] sets by transfinite induction,

- $\aleph_0=\omega$ (the least infinite ordinal which exists from the axiom of infinity, power set and separation),
- $\aleph_{\alpha+1}$ is the least ordinal whose cardinality is not smaller than $\aleph_\alpha$ (and such ordinal exists by Hartogs theorem),
- If $\delta$ is a limit ordinal, then $\aleph_\delta=\sup\{\aleph_\alpha\mid\alpha<\delta\}$ (which exists from replacement and union).

There is nothing more to it, and it's just one possible way of interpreting these cardinals. You can also represent cardinals in other ways (e.g. Scott's trick give you Scott cardinals, but it will fail you if choice *and* foundation fail, e.g. if you allow urelements and choice failed), or choose not to represent the cardinals internally and work, awkwardly I might add, with equivalence classes of sets.

It's up to you. But the consensus of what object $\aleph_0$ is exists only in set theory, and not in analysis. So asking analysts for their opinion is quite irrelevant for this question.

And so, if you identify in set theory $\Bbb N$ with $\omega$ you get that $|\Bbb N|=\Bbb N$. Whether you choose to identify the natural numbers with the finite ordinals is up to you, but most set theorists [working in $\sf ZF$ and the like] do.

At the end of the day you can argue whether or not functions are sets of ordered pairs, and whether or not $0$ is a natural number or not. At the end of the day this is just missing the point of a foundational theory. To give a foundation to *mathematics*. We have yet to find a theory that does it as well as $\sf ZFC$ (in my opinion anyway, some might argue differently).

If you're unhappy with the current foundations of mathematics, there are only two options: (1) study it and learn to accept it's supposed flaws; or (2) find a different foundation.

Comment: It seems that ZFC cannot adequately *model* (if that is the right word) what most mathematicians mean by $\aleph_0$. No great loss, I suppose.

Comment: It seems that you have no idea what you're talking about. But I suppose you're entitled to your opinion. No great loss, I suppose.

Comment: ZFC doesn't try to model what mathematicians imagine numbers, cardinals, etc "mean." It does try to model a cumulative hierarchy of pure sets in a first-order finite language with relatively simple axioms-- and the reason it is worth studying is that (virtually) all mathematical notions can be formally interpreted in ZFC. No one imagines that an ordered pair (a,b) "is really" {{a,b},{b}}, but it shows that we don't need an "outside of pure sets" primitive for ordered pairs even though the intuitive notion lies outside of pure sets (IMO anyway) . Same for cardinality. That's all.